# python-docx add horizontal line

Tags: python, python-docx

Is it possible to add a single horizontal line spanning the entire page width after a paragraph?

By using the `add_header` such a line is created after the header:

```
  document.add_heading('Test', 0)
```

I'd need such a line between two paragraphs in the document, so is it possible to just add the line by itself?

Comment: Be warned: No, the line is *not* created by `add_heading`. This only applies a [certain style](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html?highlight=add_heading#docx.document.Document.add_heading) - which, apparently, just happens to contain a paragraph rule in your text document.

Comment: Alright so is there a way to do it for normal paragraphs?

Comment: In the Word application adding what is called a "horizontal rule" is often done by setting a Paragraph style with a bottom border. However it doesn't appear the `python-docx` current supports borders in its API for `_ParagraphStyle` (or anywhere else). You might be able to fake one by inserting a graphical image or shape.

Comment: 'add_header' or  'add_heading' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported directly yet by the `python-docx` API.

However, you can achieve this effect by creating a paragraph style that has this border setting in the "template" document you open to create a new document, e.g.

```
document = Document('template-with-style.docx')
```

Then you can apply that style to a new paragraph in that document using python-docx.

Answer (score 7):

This is possible through the python-docx API using low-level functions. This is taken from [a GitHub comment](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/105#issuecomment-442786431)

```py
from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

def insertHR(paragraph):
    p = paragraph._p  # p is the <w:p> XML element
    pPr = p.get_or_add_pPr()
    pBdr = OxmlElement('w:pBdr')
    pPr.insert_element_before(pBdr,
        'w:shd', 'w:tabs', 'w:suppressAutoHyphens', 'w:kinsoku', 'w:wordWrap',
        'w:overflowPunct', 'w:topLinePunct', 'w:autoSpaceDE', 'w:autoSpaceDN',
        'w:bidi', 'w:adjustRightInd', 'w:snapToGrid', 'w:spacing', 'w:ind',
        'w:contextualSpacing', 'w:mirrorIndents', 'w:suppressOverlap', 'w:jc',
        'w:textDirection', 'w:textAlignment', 'w:textboxTightWrap',
        'w:outlineLvl', 'w:divId', 'w:cnfStyle', 'w:rPr', 'w:sectPr',
        'w:pPrChange'
    )
    bottom = OxmlElement('w:bottom')
    bottom.set(qn('w:val'), 'single')
    bottom.set(qn('w:sz'), '6')
    bottom.set(qn('w:space'), '1')
    bottom.set(qn('w:color'), 'auto')
    pBdr.append(bottom)
```

This will add a horizontal rule to a paragraph.

Comment: Best solution! Did not understand much of it, but used it for a footer by just replacing "bottom" with "top".

Comment: Hey any guidance on how to insert HR between two runs with in the same paragraph.

Comment: @IbrahimNoor, it's been a long while since I've used this. Is it worth posting a separate question with what you've tried?

Answer (score -2):

Just add

```
document.add_paragraph("_____________________________________________")
```

length of this line may not be enough but you can add it ,i hope you have solved your problems this is for new comers

Comment: This is not a good solution. It will be completely FUBAR the document's cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: Depending on the font type it will give you an interrupted line - not what most people want.

Comment: Smart. this got me laughing. lol